# Strange css issue with magento

Tags: magento-1.9, css

It was okay the other day. Magento is pointing to the correct style-sheet. I have made changes to it which were successfully uploaded but when I do a code inspect element, the file doesnt show the changes. However if I go through the file manager in my Plesk, the changes I made do show?!

Comment: Clear the browser cache, clear magento's cache, if you use the minified css, rebuild the minified version.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Clear your megento cache**

- Log into your Magento Admin Panel.
- Go to System ->> Cache Management.
- Click on the “Flush Cache Storage” button.

**2.Clear you browser cache**

**3. Rebuild you rendering tools to make magnification**

**4. check you css path too**